# Sent Data with Modem on Booting Beagle

Tags: python, websocket, cron, beagleboneblack, modem

I want to run my python program sent data to server with websocket. I want run my program on booting, so I put my program in crontab with this code :

```
crontab -e
@reboot /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/vcs/vcs.py
@reboot bash /usr/local/bin/vcs/onmodem.sh
```

in on modem.sh there is the code:

```
sleep (120)
wvdial &
```

I got ppp0 but my vcs.py didn't sent any data. Then I try to run my program without booting, my program run and sent data.
How this problem can solved?
Thankyou for the advise

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run your program at startup, I suggest to create a dedicated service.

[System and service manager](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd)

You can define your service by using the following lines, or directly call you script named modem.sh

```
ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c 'sleep 120'
ExecStart=/usr/bin/wvdial &
```